# CkeckBox has map returning Null

Tags: java, android, hashmap

This is my code, the Spawn method gets called when a button is pressed:

```
     public void Spawn (View V) {
       LayoutInflater inflater =
       (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
       View iv = inflater.inflate( R.layout.motor_block, null );
       //LinearLayout iv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.motor_block);
       RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
       CheckBox A = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
       boxesA.put(currentKey,A);
       CheckBox B = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
       boxesB.put(currentKey,B);
       CheckBox C = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
       boxesC.put(currentKey,C);
       iv.setTag(currentKey);
       rl.addView(iv);
       currentKey ++; 
            iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean  onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                        iAction = event.getActionMasked();
                    switch (iAction) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        v.getLocationOnScreen(aLocation);                   // get absolute physical location of this View
                        iOffsetX =  (aLocation [ 0 ] - (int) v.getX());     // subtract out this View's relative location within its parent View...
                        iOffsetY =  (aLocation [ 1 ] - (int) v.getY());     // ...yielding the offsets that convert getRawX/Y's coords to setX/Y's coords

                        iNewX = (int) event.getRawX();                      // get absolute physical coords of this touch
                        iNewY = (int) event.getRawY();
                        iNewX -= iOffsetX;                                  // remove parent View's screen offset (calc'd above)
                        iNewY -= iOffsetY;
                        iNewX -= iRelX;                                     // remove stored touch offset
                        iNewY -= iRelY;
                        v.setX(iNewX);                                      // finally, move View to new coords (relative to its parent View)
                        v.setY(iNewY);
                        bExitValue = true;          
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (delete){ v.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
                        iRelX = (int) event.getX();                         // preserve offset of this touch within the View
                        iRelY = (int) event.getY();
                        bExitValue = false;
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        bExitValue = true;
                    break;

                    }
                    return (bExitValue);


                }
            });

               iv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        v.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
                        if (!bExitValue) {
                            Log.i("TAG",(String) v.getTag());

                            int key = (Integer) v.getTag();
                            CheckBox A = boxesA.get(key);
                            CheckBox B = boxesB.get(key);
                            CheckBox C = boxesC.get(key);
                        if (A.isChecked()){   //A IS NULL
                            Log.i("Checked","A");
                        }
                        if (B.isChecked()){
                            Log.i("Checked","B");
                        }
                        if (C.isChecked()){
                            Log.i("Checked","C");
                        }

                        Log.i("Click","LONG");
                        v.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

   }
```

In this method, a View is spawned which has three check-boxes in it.
I just put them in a Hash-map with an Integer as a key.
It turns out that A is null, which makes no sense to me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about B and C? They are fine or they are also null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the view to your layout before trying to access the CheckBox views that are part of it. Any attempt to access those views before they have been rendered will return null, because they haven't been created yet.